# Oracle-Trigger to skip duplicate values

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

I have an Oracle CSV bulk import script. Fear is that the file might contain logically identical data and thus raising an unique key constraint violation.

So I thought a trigger might do the trick, only insert data if new. Here is my trigger.

```
create or replace trigger no_double
before insert or update on test_table
for each row
declare
  checkval number;
begin
  select count(1) into checkval from test_table
  where keyvalue = :new.keyvalue
  if (checkval = 0) then
    insert into test_table(keyvalue, field1) 
    values (:new.keyvalue, :new.field1);
  end if;
end;
```

But of course once the script actually inserts a new value to *test_table*, the trigger re-triggers and so on.

One workaround might be to introduce a second table and copy data on *after insert*. But I was hoping for a more elegant solution, so (if indeed possible) how can I avoid inserting duplicated values at the database layer (a silent skip would be okay, too).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG

Comment: Good point, then I would want to hide the *ignore_row_on_dupkey_index*-hint in a *instead of insert*-Trigger. But apparently I can only utilize the instead of insert in a View, so again I would need a second database object?